Anchor-generated TypeScript issue
I tried to execute this instruction https://github.com/triadxyz/spl-404/blob/99dd63ba9905c04a191f2c21d44fcc8449880240/programs/spl-404/src/instructions/mint_token.rs
using JS sdk.
I've got an error: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing.
But based on the SPL I send all parameters. It seems that JS doesn't work as expected.
Js code: https://github.com/triadxyz/spl-404/blob/99dd63ba9905c04a191f2c21d44fcc8449880240/sdk/src/test.ts#L111

The program is using anchor 0.30.0 and is using automatic account resolution and I think that might be the cause of your issues.
Try changing to using accountStrict and add all the accounts manually.
ref: https://www.anchor-lang.com/release-notes/0.30.0#account-resolution

Thanks, I used accountsPartial and just added the missing account. It worked fine after that.
